# open new tabs on NavBarItem clicked in Devexpress

Tags: devexpress

I'm developing some Windows forms app with Devexpress, and I have something like below, a set of tabs are open which are related to "System parameters" and I want to a new set of tabs to open in place of older tabs when I click on Error navBarItem and also it should be vise versa, I saw this in demos but I don't know how to do it myself, thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a `UserControl` for each set of options, and when you click on an item of your navigation bar, you do the following :

- Set the visible property of the current user control to false
- Check if the user control associed to the clicked item exist, if yes, set it's visible property to true (reactivate it), otherwise, create an new instance of it, and dock it.

To manage this, you should have a a list of the user controls already opened, so you can reactivate them when needed.

[This link](http://www.differentpla.net/content/2004/10/implementing-a-paged-options-dialog) may help you :-)

Comment: thanks, I already could implement it in a way like that, put some tabContorls in the page, and hided all at first and showed them as I wished, maybe not the best approach, but worked for me.